# How to add empty new line in block quote?

Tags: support, blockquote, indentation

Not sure if this is a duplicate.

I can have the following in a block quote:

> Case 1
>
> 00:23
>
> 00:54
>
> Case 2
>
> 00:21
>
> 00:51

But this makes it look clumsy. I want the following actually:

> Case 1
>
> 00:23
>
> 00:54
>
> --1 additional empty line here
>
> Case 2
>
> 00:21
>
> 00:51

so that each cases are separate and can be easily identified. If its not possible, is there a similar alternative pattern I can use here?

Comment: Alternatives: You could highlight the case headings, such as by making them bold, or separate them with a horizontal line.

Comment: @RobKennedy I get it about bold thing, but I dont understand that horizontal thing. Could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Like this:

```
> Case 1
> 
> 00:23
> 
> 00:54
> 
> &nbsp;
> 
> Case 2
> 
> 00:21
> 
> 00:51
```

Which produces:

> Case 1
>
> 00:23
>
> 00:54
>
> Case 2
>
> 00:21
>
> 00:51

Alternatively, placing two spaces at the end of a line with no empty line after it creates a line break rather than a new paragraph, which would probably look better:

```
> Case 1  
> 00:23  
> 00:54  
> 
> Case 2  
> 00:21  
> 00:51
```

> Case 1
>   00:23
>   00:54
>
> Case 2
>   00:21
>   00:51

Comment: The **two spaces** at the end is exactly what is breaking the line. Thanks for that, I was searching for condensing, too.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of alternatives to an empty line that would still serve to visually distinguish your two sections of text. First, you could highlight the case headings:

```
> **Case 1**
> 
> 00:23
> 
> 00:54
> 
> **Case 2**
> 
> 00:21
> 
> 00:51
```

> **Case 1**
>
> 00:23
>
> 00:54
>
> **Case 2**
>
> 00:21
>
> 00:51

Second, you could use a horizontal line:

```
> Case 1
> 
> 00:23
> 
> 00:54
> 
> ----
> 
> Case 2
> 
> 00:21
> 
> 00:51
```

> Case 1
>
> 00:23
>
> 00:54
>
> ---
>
> Case 2
>
> 00:21
>
> 00:51