# How to add a blank line in a blockquote?

Tags: support, markdown, blockquote

I'd like to do know how to do the following:

> Blockquote A

*blank line that's not part of either block, visually distinguishing two different blockquotes*

> Blockquote B

#### Experiments

Without adding a text in between it looks like:

> Blockquote A
>
> Blockquote B

I tried separating them by adding a line, like so:

> Blockquote A
>
> ---
>
> Blockquote B

But visually, I think this is misleading because it can imply that the quotes are from the same source (when they aren't per se). So I prefer to show a blank line between the blockquotes.

#### Research

I've found a related question: [How to add empty new line in block quote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186645/how-to-add-empty-new-line-in-block-quote). But these answers don't address what I want to do, 
I can't seem to find the way to do this seemingly simple trick. I've already looked into the [Markup help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes), but I might be overlooking it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I separate multiple quote blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298962/how-can-i-separate-multiple-quote-blocks) Whoopsie ;)

Comment: @Marshmallow Oh great, couldn't find that one, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the trick to add a `<!>` in between:

> Blockquote A

> Blockquote B

Comment: Accepting this one, because this way looks the most tight and is easy to remember. Also see [these answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298962/how-can-i-separate-multiple-quote-blocks) for more methods.

Comment: <!-- MD028/no-blanks-blockquote -->

between them should work if you want to ignore the rule

Another approach is to use backslash as a <br />

Answer (score 3):

Something like below I added `&nbsp;` in between.

> Blockquote A

> Blockquote B

Answer (score 2):

`<br>` also work.

> Blockquote A

> Blockquote B